# React Native package conflict: native-base x react-native-firebase

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, react-native, native-base

Today I created an (empty) Android app using the "react-native-firebase" and "native-base" packages. It works in debug mode, but in release mode crash occurs.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create a new app

   ```
   react-native init BaseTest

   cd BaseTest
   ```
2. Install the "native-base"

   ```
   npm install native-base --save

   react-native link
   ```
3. Install the "react-native-firebase"

   ```
   https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.*/installation/initial-setup

   https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.*/installation/android
   ```
4. Generating Signed APK

   ```
   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html
   ```
5. Build release and install

   ```
   cd android

   gradlew assembleRelease

   adb install app-release.apk
   ```

I could not find the error. Does anyone have any ideas?[image]

Comment: What's the problem that happens in release mode? Please include the error message/stack trace in your question. If the error message points to your code, include the relevant code too.

Comment: Frank, thank you, my code just import the packages, I edit the question with a picture of the crash.

Comment: What version of RN? Show output of `adb logcat`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the same issue and it really aced my head but I managed to resolve it. So instead of running

`react-native link` run `react-native link **native-base**.`

I hope this helps. Happy coding :)